# Approx the jump point of a $BV$ function from both hand side

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $I=(-1,1)$ be an interval in one dimension. Let $u\in BV(I)$ be defined as
$$
u(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if }x\in(-1,0)\\
1,&\text{ if }x\in(0,1)
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, we have $u\in BV$ and $S_u$, the jump point of $u$, is at $0$. We shall use $Du$ to dentoe the weak derivative of $u$ in $BV$ space, and $u'$ the absolutely continuous part of $Du$.

Now let $u_n$ be a sequence of $BV$ function such that $u_n\to u$ strong in $L^1$.

My question: Does there exists a function $f_n$ defined on $\mathbb R^+$ such that

1. $f_n\to 1$ a.e.,
2. if
   $$
   \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_{I}f_n(|u_n'(x)|)dx<\infty
   $$
   then we have
   $$
   \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_{I}f_n(|u_n'(x)|)dx\geq\int_I|u'|dx
   $$
   and for sufficit large $n$, we have $S_{u_n}\Delta S_u=\varnothing$ and there exists $x_n$, $y_n\in S_{u_n}$ such that 
   $$ 
   x_n<0<y_n
   $$
   and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0$? (Recall $S_u=\{0\}$)

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by $u_n\to u$ in $BV$ weak sense?

Comment: @FanZheng I updated the post. Thanks for pointing out!